# Making an add method for an ArrayList

Tags: java, if-statement, methods, for-loop, arraylist

So I am supposed to make an add method for an array list which adds a new movie object to the list if it doesnt exist, or if it finds a movie object with a similar title within the list, it just increases the quantity property of that object. Here is what I've got so far.

```
public void add(String title, double rating, int releaseYear){

    if(this.myMovies.size() < 1)
    {
        Movie mymovie = new Movie(title, rating, releaseYear);
        this.myMovies.add(mymovie);
    }

    else
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < this.myMovies.size(); i++)
        {
            Movie temp = this.myMovies.get(i);

            if(temp.Title.equals(title)){
                this.myMovies.get(i).quantity++;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                Movie mymovie = new Movie(title, rating, releaseYear);
                this.myMovies.add(mymovie);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

My problem is that this ends up not taking account of similar names and doesn't increase the quantity but just adds another object to the list. I have a strong feeling that the problem lies within my For loop but I just can't identify it. Can anyone see anything that I may be doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Consider using `equalsIgnoreCase` instead of `equals`, which will do a case-insensitive match. What is a "similar" title anyway?

Comment: looks like `temp.Title.equals(title)` is false for every item in your list

Comment: Is `temp.Title` a String or a custom object ?
Anyway it has to start with a lower case letter.

Answer (score 1):

You're testing only for equality, not similarity here:

`if(temp.Title.equals(title)){`

Instead, you should write a helper method to test for similarity based on whatever criteria are appropriate.  For example:

`if (isSimilar(temp.Title, title)){`

and the isSimilar method might look something like this (assuming you don't need any input validation):

```
private void isSimilar(String title1, String title2) {
    return title1.equalsIgnoreCase(title2)
        || title1.toLowerCase().contains(title2.toLowerCase())
        || title2.toLowerCase().contains(title1.toLowerCase());
}
```

or, perhaps more appropriately, like this (if you implement it in the Movie class):

```
private void isSimilar(otherMovie) {
    return title.equalsIgnoreCase(otherMovie.title)
        || title.toLowerCase().contains(otherMovie.title.toLowerCase())
        || otherMovie.title.toLowerCase().contains(title.toLowerCase());
}
```

...in which case your `if` statement would also change slightly.

Keep in mind that I don't know what you consider 'similar'; only that the movies are considered similar if the names are similar.

A couple more comments:

1. Fields and method names generally start with a lowercase letter (so the field `Movie.Title` should instead be `Movie.title`).
2. It's usually preferable to loop over a `Collection` using an `Iterator` instead of using the raw index--partly because the `Iterator` should always know how to loop over the `Collection` efficiently.
3. Learn to use your IDE's debugger (it's probably very easy).  Then you can step through each line of code to see exactly where your program is doing something unexpected.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
public void add(String title, double rating, int releaseYear){
    for(Movie m: myMovies.size())
    {
        if(m.Title.equals(title)){
            m.quantity++;
            return;
        }
    }
    // movie with same title not found in the list -> insert 
    this.myMovies.add(new Movie(title, rating, releaseYear));
}
```

By the way: variable names should start with a lowercase character (`Title` -> `title`).

Comment: I'm so sorry to confuse you guys. Instead of saying similar I should have said equals. My english is bad and I'm going to retake English 101 :/

Answer (score 0):

I'm addressing your "similarity" requirement. If you really want to do this properly it could be a lot of work. Essentially you have two strings and want to get a measure of the similarity. I am doing the same thing for figure captions and I plan to tackle it by:

- splitting the title into words
- lowercasing them
- using them as features for classifier4J (http://classifier4j.sourceforge.net/)

That will go a long way based on simple word counts. But then you have the problem of stemming
(words that differ by endings - "Alien" and "Aliens"). If you go down this road you'll need to read up about Classification and Natural Language Processing